# Uncaught ReferenceError: Swiper is not defined at script.js:1:14 (anonymous) @ script.js:1

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

I am facing an error of Uncaught Reference while using Swiper js on the website. Please help me...

```
var swiper = new Swiper('.slide-content', {
    slidesPerView: 3,
    spaceBetween: 25,
    loop: true,
    centerSlide: 'true',
    fade: 'true',
    grabCursor: 'true',
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
        dynamicBullets: true,
    },
    navigation: {
        nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
        prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
    },
});
```

Comment: You have to include the swiper javascript before your own script: `<script src="swiper.js"></script><script>var swiper = new Swiper...</script>`

Comment: yess, it worked